# Show that $\phi(n)\sigma(n)<n^2$ ,for all $n>1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, problem-solving

Let $\phi$ denote the Euler's phi function and $\sigma$ denote the sum of divisors function,then I want to show that $n^2>\phi(n)\sigma(n)$,I was trying to proceed using prime factorisation as follows:

Let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_k^{\alpha_k}$ then $\phi(n)\sigma(n)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^kp^{\alpha_i-1}(p^{\alpha_i+1}-1)$.

Now I observed that for $k=2$,

$n^2=p_1^{2\alpha_1}p_2^{2\alpha_2}>p_1^{2\alpha_1}p_2^{2\alpha_2}-p_1^{\alpha_1-1}p_2^{\alpha_2-1}.(p_1^{\alpha_1+1}+p_2^{\alpha_2+1}-1)=\phi(n)\sigma(n)$.

But for $k\geq 3$ there will be lots of product terms in $\phi(n)\sigma(n)$,then how to show the same inequality?

Comment: I suggest you consider the case where $k = 1$, then recall that if $a < b$ and $c < d$ then $ac < bd$ for positive $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d.$

Comment: @user24142 I did not understand,please write an answer.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar FYI, several fairly closely related questions here are [How find the numbers of $n$ such $\sigma{(n)}\varphi{(n)}>n^2-n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/505843/602049), [Can we improve on the inequality $\sigma(N)\varphi(N) < N^2$ for integers $N > 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3388291/602049) and [Can we improve on the inequality $\sigma(N)\varphi(N) < N^2$ for composite integers $N > 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3417085/602049). Also, there's an [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1567709p9607270) thread, in particular #$5$ there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from what you've done,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\prod_{i=1}^k p^{\alpha_i-1}(p^{\alpha_i+1}-1) & = \prod_{i=1}^k (p^{2\alpha_i}-p^{\alpha_i-1}) \\
& \lt \prod_{i=1}^k p^{2\alpha_i} \\
& = \left(\prod_{i=1}^k p^{\alpha_i}\right)^2 \\
& = n^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$